# Haskell - How to only print a certain tuple in a list of tuples which has the highest number?

Tags: haskell

Sorry i am new to haskell, i'm not sure if i have worded this poroperly.

if I have a list of tuples, for example:

```
testData = [("Jack", "Hill", 2), ("Susan", "Smith", 5), ("Steve", "Johnson", 6)]
```

how would I be able to display the tuple with the biggest number? Which in this case would be

```
("Steve", "Johnson", 6)
```

Comment: look at the example for [`maximumBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:maximumBy)

Comment: I tried that but i am not sure how to use it in a list of tuples

Comment: Well, `maximumBy` takes a function and a list, where that function takes one of the list elements as an argument and produces something that's comparable, and outputs the list element that produces the maximum result when that function is applied. Hopefully it's fairly obvious from that what function you need here. (Hint: it's very simple, don't overthink it!)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ry in the comment section, you can use `maximumBy`:

```hs
import Data.List (maximumBy)
import Data.Function (on)

main = print $ maximumBy (compare `on` third) testData -- ("Steve","Johnson",6)

testData :: [(String, String, Int)]
testData = [("Jack", "Hill", 2), ("Susan", "Smith", 5), ("Steve", "Johnson", 6)]

third :: (a, b, c) -> c
third (_, _, c) = c
```

Here, I defined a function `third` to get the third element from a 3-tuple. Then `on` uses this to provide a function of type `a -> a -> Ordering` which is required by `maximumBy`. Actually `` compare `on` third `` is equivalent to `\x y -> compare (third x) (third y)`.